# Finding http in a href expression <a href=“javascript:;”></a> and replace it with https

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, hyperlink

I have some links in the form of `<a href="javascript:;` and I need to find the `http` in them and replace it with `https://`

Simple writing a JS code for finding `http` doesn't work in this case and I am completely stuck.
What would be the best method to find a link in an expression like `<a href="javascript:some very long lines;">Link</a>` ?

An image with links in reality:
[image]
Many thanks!

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let url = document.querySelectorAll('.page-numbers');

    url.forEach((e) => {
      e.setAttribute('href', e.href.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://'));
      console.log(e);

    }); 
};
```

```html
<div class="pagingSection">
      <a href="javascript:WebF(new WebFform("ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0", "", false, "", "http://www.example.com/test.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=6", false, true))" class="page-numbers">Link 1</a>
      <a href="javascript:WebF(new WebFform("ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0", "", false, "", "http://www.example.com/test2.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=7", false, true))" class="page-numbers">Link 2</a>
      <a href="javascript:WebF(new WebFform("ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0", "", false, "", "http://www.example.com/test3.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=8", false, true))" class="page-numbers">Link 3</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your `href` attributes in that HTML end as of the first `"` you tried to put in the attribute, since you're using `"` to quote the attribute value. If you use a literal `"` within the value and you don't use a literal `'` within it, quote the attribute with `'` instead of `"`. Otherwise, you can use `&quot;` since attribute text is HTML text.

Other than that, I'd use `getAttribute` rather than the `href` accessor property to get the old value, and you don't want to start your regular expression with `^` since you want to match somewhere other than the very beginning of the string. Here I use `\b` (word boundary):

```js
const pageNums = document.querySelectorAll(".page-numbers");
for (const e of pageNums) {
    e.setAttribute(
        "href",
        e.getAttribute("href").replace(/\bhttp:\/\//g, "https://")
    );
    console.log(e.href);
}
```

```html
<div class="pagingSection">
    <a href='javascript:WebF(new WebFform("ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0", "", false, "", "http://www.example.com/test.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=6", false, true))' class="page-numbers">Link 1</a>
    <a href='javascript:WebF(new WebFform("ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0", "", false, "", "http://www.example.com/test2.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=7", false, true))' class="page-numbers">Link 2</a>
    <a href='javascript:WebF(new WebFform("ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0", "", false, "", "http://www.example.com/test3.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=8", false, true))' class="page-numbers">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Note that I've also moved that code out of the `load` event handler. The `window` `load` event happesn **very** late in the page load process, waiting for all resources including images to load before firing. Instead of using `load` for this, do one of these things if possible (this is an **or** list, do the first one that fits your target environment/browsers):

- Add `type="module"` to the `script` tag so it doesn't get run until the HTML is completely loaded and runs within a module scope rather than at global scope. (All major modern browsers support modules. Don't do this if you need to support IE11, but you're using arrow functions, so I assume you don't, though you could be transpiling.)
- Add `defer` to the `script` tag so it doesn't get run until the HTML is completely loaded. Even IE11 supports `defer`.
- Put the `script` tag at the end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag.
- Wrap your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` handler rather than a `load` handler.

---

Side note: I'd suggest **not** putting JavaScript code in the `href` in the first place. Instead, make the `href` something meaningful, ideally that takes you somewhere helpful if JavaScript is disabled, and attach your event handlers using modern event handling (perhaps using event delegation) and have the JavaScript code prevent the default action (following the link) if it runs. For instance:

```js
const pageNums = document.querySelectorAll(".page-numbers");
for (const e of pageNums) {
    e.setAttribute(
        "data-target",
        e.getAttribute("data-target").replace(/\bhttp:\/\//g, "https://")
    );
    console.log(e.href);
}

// The handler
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const link = event.target.closest(".page-numbers");
    if (link) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = link.getAttribute("data-form");
        const target = link.getAttribute("data-target");
        WebF(new WebFform(form, "", false, "", target, false, true));
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="pagingSection">
    <a href="#some-meaningful-value" data-form="ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0" data-target="http://www.example.com/test.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=6" class="page-numbers">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#some-meaningful-value" data-form="ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0" data-target="http://www.example.com/test2.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=7" class="page-numbers">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#some-meaningful-value" data-form="ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0" data-target="http://www.example.com/test3.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=8" class="page-numbers">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Now you don't have to muck about with escaping quotes or picking quotes based on whether you've used `"` or `'` for the attribute delimiter, your JavaScript code is in a script file, etc.

In fact, come to think of it, the handler could even handle the `http://` => `https://` thing for you:

```js
    const link = event.target.closest(".page-numbers");
    if (link) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = link.getAttribute("data-form");
        // (Using `^` now because it *is* at the beginning of the string)
        const target = link.getAttribute("data-target").replace(/^http:\/\//g, "https://");
        WebF(new WebFform(form, "", false, "", target, false, true));
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="pagingSection">
    <a href="#some-meaningful-value" data-form="ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0" data-target="http://www.example.com/test.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=6" class="page-numbers">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#some-meaningful-value" data-form="ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0" data-target="http://www.example.com/test2.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=7" class="page-numbers">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#some-meaningful-value" data-form="ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0" data-target="http://www.example.com/test3.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=8" class="page-numbers">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @t-j-crowder Thanks for the advice! 

Someone here mentioned that links aren't in proper format. I edited my post to add an image with the links the way I'm seeing them. In this case, your solution still applies?

If I click on a link in dev console, I'm getting those very long lines which were cropped a little to avoid displaying the whole information.

Comment: @JustMe - Yes, still applies, other than that your original question had different code within the links than is in the image, so you'll need to adjust the above for that. I added to the answer BTW. Happy coding!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - It's an ordered list of alternatives, best to least. :-) I've clarified that.

Comment: @t-j-crowder I tried your first snippet and console.log reports proper transformation of http into https but  also I'm seeing an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at <anonymous>:5:31
(anonymous) @ VM10308:5` What can be the cause of this?

Comment: @JustMe - Sounds like one of the `.page-numbers` elements has no `href` attribute. You can add a guard: `const value = e.getAttribute("href"); if (value) { e.setAttribute( "href", value.replace(/\bhttp:\/\//g, "https://")); }`

Answer (score 1):

- Use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` to target the Element's `"href"` attr.
- Use [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with the `$&` **replacement pattern** (*matched substring*)
- (PS: make sure to use the proper quotes in HTML)
- Always use `Element.addEventListener()` instead of `on*` handlers (unless you're creating a brand new Element from in-memory) to not override other assigned handlers.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const EL_anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.page-numbers');
  EL_anchors.forEach(EL =>
    EL.setAttribute("href", EL.getAttribute("href").replace(/\bhttp(?=:\/\/)/, "$&s"))
  );
});
```

```html
<div class="pagingSection">
  <a href='javascript:WebF(new WebFform("ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0", "", false, "", "http://www.example.com/test.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=6", false, true))' class="page-numbers">Link 1</a>
  <a href='javascript:WebF(new WebFform("ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0", "", false, "", "http://www.example.com/test2.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=7", false, true))' class="page-numbers">Link 2</a>
  <a href='javascript:WebF(new WebFform("ctl01$ctl8$g_8f9c2af0", "", false, "", "http://www.example.com/test3.aspx?cor=%20;403-7e1ee457616b%7%20;0374d4027-5a27-4421-9771-6326d4746a20%7%20ol;&areaId=%=8", false, true))' class="page-numbers">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

```
\b         << Word boundary
http       << Match substring (Reused later with the .replace() `$&` pattern)
(?=:\/\/)  << Positive lookahead: followed by "://"
```

where the `.replace()`'s second argument pattern does:

```
$&   << insert the matcher "http" substring
s    << insert the character "s"
```

To replace globally you could also use the `g` flag: `/\bhttp(?=:\/\/)/g`

Answer (score -2):

you just have to place the matching string into parentheses:

```
let string = "http://www.test.com";
string.replace(/(http:\/\/)/, "https://");
```

Comment: No, you don't. You only need `()` if you want a capture group.